# Share an access Database on Sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, vba, sharepoint-2007, ms-access-2016

I have created quite a large Access 2016 db. It is now ready to share with the business and needs to be put onto SharePoint. I've tried just uploading the file to a SharePoint document library, however users cannot edit the database (there is a lot of VBA code that runs SQL commands that write data input by users into the database).

Is there a way to share the database that allows users to open it from SharePoint and let the VBA write to the database/tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as SharePoint isn't an *SMB* fileshare, neither is OneDrive, DropBox, etc.

The SMB fileshare is offered by a *Windows Server* or a Linux box with *Samba* installed.

Comment: If I split the database, can the front end be stored on SharePoint with the db on a network drive?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to copy it to a local folder. You can use the method described here: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html) or similar.